# Inside a div, how can I set a "cell spacing"?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Let's suppose there are many divs inside a div:

```
<div id="#container">
 div div div div
</div>
```

the inner divs can be next to each other even. Now I want to have 5px padding between all of then, just like `cellspacing` of `table`.

Comment: Padding is not given between different divs. Padding is the space between content of an element and border. I think you need 5px space/gap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you would do something like:

```
 #container div
 {
     margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
 }
```

or for only the immediate children:

```
 #container > div
 {
     margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
 }
```

if you want the divs to go side-by-side you have to float them:

```
 #container div
 {
     float:left;
     clear:none;
     margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
 }
```

Comment: its ok, but if I do "5px 5px 5px 5px;" it falls apart

Comment: What do you mean 'Falls apart'? That would just mean that the margin between the divs are 10px in total since you're adding 5px on all sides of all divs...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use CSS for that.

```
<div id="container">
   <div style="padding:5px 5px 0 0;">
   </div>
   <div style="padding:5px 5px 0 0;">
   </div>
</div>
```

Basically, any element in HTML can be positioned and styled using either inline css (like above) or in a separate stylesheet, using the CSS syntax.

in this case, padding would mean that the element will have 5 pixels of space inside it's content, whilst margin would mean that it would have 5 pixels of space outside it's bounds.

Comment: -1 OP asked for "5px padding between all of them" this would give 10px  padding.

Comment: Fixed, but he would have been able to tune it to his own needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
#container div {
  margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}
```

Comment: -1 OP asked for "5px padding between all of them" this would give 10px  padding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either padding or margin in this case.

But if you have visible border for divs then use margin. Otherwise it will not look like cell spacing.